# Powershell get timezone with DST

Tags: powershell, utc, dst, timezone-offset

In powershell I'm using

```
(Get-Timezone).BaseUtcOffset
```

to get the UTC offset of a computer which gives me +1h for my timezone. That is technically correct since I'm in CET in winter (UTC+1) and CEST in summer (UTC+2). Right now tho it is DST, so CEST (UTC+2) for me so I'm wondering how I could get this information in powershell since the above command tells me that my timezone is UTC+1 and doesn't mention DST at all.

As a workaround I currently use

```
$date = Get-Date
($date - $date.ToUniversalTime()).TotalMinutes
```

to get the offset from UTC of my timezone with DST. It evaluates to +120 minutes which is exactly what i need.

Output of Get-Timezone:

```
Id                         : W. Europe Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien
StandardName               : Mitteleuropäische Zeit
DaylightName               : Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
BaseUtcOffset              : 01:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

Output of $date - $date.ToUniversalTime():

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 2
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 72000000000
TotalDays         : 0,0833333333333333
TotalHours        : 2
TotalMinutes      : 120
TotalSeconds      : 7200
TotalMilliseconds : 7200000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the static method [`IsDaylightSavingTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime) on the  [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) class to get this information from a desired [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime):

```
$now = [DateTime]::Now
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.IsDaylightSavingTime($now) # Returns $True or $False
```

Answer (score 2):

thank you [Bender the Greatest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584676/bender-the-greatest) you got me on the right path. The class System.TimeZoneInfo has a function that does what i want:

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.GetUtcOffset((Get-Date)).TotalMinutes
```

gives me +120 minutes

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you an Offset + DST in HH::MM format

```
"UTC"+(Get-Date -Format "%K")
```